# Error after update to Xcode 7

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

I have browsed through some of the other posts relating to upgrade and errors but I did not see one that I thought answered my issue. The following code was working yesterday but today after upgrading, I am getting an error:

```
enteredDataArrayOne = [enterDate.text, enterSeason.text, enterSport.text, enterDispTo.text]
```

The error is as follows:

```
Cannot assign a value of type '[String?]' to a value of type 'NSArray'
```

I am very new to coding. I have gone back to review my instructional materials and it is my understanding that building an array of strings is allowed. The values that make up the array `enteredDataArrayOne` are the values of text fields entered by the user.

Here are the other two places that this array is used:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "goToDispenseScreenTwo") {
        let DestViewControllerTwo = segue.destinationViewController as! DispenseScreenTwoViewController;
        DestViewControllerTwo.toPassTwo = enteredDataArrayOne as! [String]
    }
}
```

and then later in the same method where the array is built:

```
if blankData != 1 {
        //add code to pass data to next veiw controller
        enteredDataArrayOne = [enterDate.text, enterSeason.text, enterSport.text, enterDispTo.text]
        print(enteredDataArrayOne)
        self.appIsWorking ()
        performSegueWithIdentifier("goToDispenseScreenTwo", sender: self)
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    }
```

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix your error

```
enteredDataArrayOne = [enterDate.text!, enterSeason.text!, enterSport.text!, enterDispTo.text!]
```

Comment: That worked. Could you tell me why I needed the exclamation point? That would help me to understand for the future.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Greg `NSArray` cannot hold `nil` values. Optional value (`something?`) means that the value can be `nil`. Using `!` forces a crash if the value is `nil` so we can be sure there is no `nil` value.

Comment: As @Sulthan suggested the problem is that without the `!` you implicitly accept the value to be, possibly, `nil` which is not accepted in this case for `NSArray`. I suggest you to refer to any tutorial about `Optionals` in Swift. Like this one or anyone else http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/swift-optionals-use-let/

Comment: Thank you both for that information. I have read about nil values but I did not realize that is what I was leaving as an option. The code will not run unless all required fields are populated but I can see how Xcode does not know that. Again, thank you both for your time and expertise.

Comment: The exclamation point will cause the app to crash in case any of the four items is nil and be definition any one of them can be nil. Do not use force unwrapping (exclamation point) unless you are 100% sure that the item can never, under any circumstances be nil–ever!